# Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) when push code to gitlab from Android studio

Tags: android-studio, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

After update git, I just come up with a problem that when I push or pull code between android studio and gitlab, there is a problem:

```
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have searched online and found there is connection problem about the ssh, but

I still can clone project to my local machine.

I have checked the ssh public key on my pc and gitlab, they are still there.

My github works normally, and I can push or pull code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ssh -T git@<yourGitLabServer>` does work (meaning you get a "Welcome" message), check if you can query the repo with:

```
git ls-remote git@<yourGitLabServer>:<user>/repo
```

If that is the case, then there must be a permission issue, which prevents you to push (as in, you are no longer a collaborator on that project)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However I'm getting this error when I created new private repo under my account....

`ssh -T..` works. And `git ls-remote...` returns that permission issue.

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs that means the user you are authenticated with SSH does not have the right to access the repository.tested with `git lsremote`.

Comment: Ha, I had `GIT_SSH` env variable set to `C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe` (Windows machine). I tried [debug cloning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/useful_git_commands.html#debug-cloning) `$env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"` and it just worked... because ssh.exe is `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs Good catch. That should work better indeed.